# failed to print the pattern as expected for a given positive integer n in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, arraylist

I wanted to print a particular pattern as shown below and for that, I created a list of lists with just `[1]` in it.

Then I ran a for loop from `i= 2 to n` and in each iteration, I have added `[i]*(2i-3)` in top of the list as well as in the bottom.

Then add `i` on both sides of all sub_lists.

Below is the code i have used:

```
answer=[[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
  t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
  answer.insert(0, t)
  answer.append(t)
  for a in answer:
    a.insert(0,i)
    a.append(i)

answerfinal=[]

print(len(answer))

# we join the elements of the string without space
for a in answer:
  answerfinal.append(''.join(map(str, a)))
#print 
for a in answerfinal:
    print(a)
```

I was supposing to get an answer like this, if input given is 4 :

```
4444444
4333334
4322234
4321234
4322234
4333334
4444444
```

But what I got is this:

```
444444444
44333333344
4433222223344
4321234
4433222223344
44333333344
444444444
```

Not sure where I was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the key Python blunders.  The problem here is that you create the list `t`, then you add `t` to the beginning, then you add THE VERY SAME `t` to the end.  It's not a copy, it is a reference to the same list.  So, when you run through the list of lines, you're adding to the ends twice.  Change

```
  answer.append(t)
```

to

```
  answer.append(t[:])
```